# Looking for JPOS Tutorial

Tags: iso8583, jpos

I am new to ISO8583 concept.From several days I am searching for a nice and detailed tutorial for JPOS library. Does any one suggest me . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

What about clicking in the "Tutorials" link in the http://jpos.org website?

http://jpos.org/tutorials

Answer (score 3):

[Here you have a complete Programmer's guide of jPOS](http://jpos.org/doc/proguide-draft.pdf)  and [Here a list of 3 tutorials](http://www.jpos.org/tutorials) that are good to begin learning by some use cases.

Answer (score 2):

For **jPOS** tutorials you can refer the following things:

1. [jPOS Proguide](http://jpos.org/doc/proguide-draft.pdf): Official jPOS tutorial.
2. You should also refer [Andy-o-Rock](http://www.andyorrock.com/) blog which is very helpful to start with a jPOS project.
3. You should also follow [jPOS Blog](http://jpos.org/blog/) for updates.
4. jPOS official Slack channel, which is accessible to people.

Hope this helps.